# Template spaghetti

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Please throw some light on that baffling piece of template spaghetti:

```
template <typename T, typename K> class A {
public:
    T t;
    K k;

    template <int i, int unused = 0> struct AttributeType {
    };

    template <int i> AttributeType<i> getAttr();

};

template <typename T, typename K> template <int i> A<T, K>::AttributeType<i> A<T, K>::getAttr<i>() {
    return t;
}
```

I'm not able to come up with the correct syntax to define the implementation of `A::getAttr()`. The current code fails to compile at the line of getAttr definition:

`error: function template partial specialization ‘getAttr<i>’ is not allowed`

How should I rephrase the function definition?

Comment: As a side note, rather than an answer, things are much simpler in general if you *define* the members of a template in place, rather than pulling them outside of the template definition. That is, it would be much simpler if `getAttr` was defined where it is being declared.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove that `<i>` behind the function name and add a `typename` right before the return type, it's a **dependent name**. Also, it's missing a `template` before `AttributeType` because that's a template:

```
template <typename T, typename K>
template <int i>
typename A<T, K>::template AttributeType<i> A<T, K>::getAttr() {
    return t;
}
```

Next, it is helpful to give each template part its own line. Makes stuff clearer.

Aside from that, the function looks wrong, or does `AttributeType` have a conversion constructor from `T`?

Comment: Wow, thanks! You're a true compiler-head :) I just had to add `template` before `AttributeType` and it worked:

Comment: @ognian: Not `template`, `typename`. See [this FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names).

Comment: @Xeo: template *and* typename:
`template <typename T, typename K>
template <int i>
typename A<T, K>::template AttributeType<i> A<T, K>::getAttr() {
    return t;
}`

Comment: @ognian: Interesting, VC10 fails to compile with `template`. Brb.

Comment: @ognian: This is bothering me, so please take a look at [this follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232294/which-compiler-is-right-template-before-templated-return-type-needed). :)

Comment: @ognian: I'll trust GCC and Comeau for now and edit the `template`, for correctness' sake.