# Which compiler is right? 'template' before templated return type needed?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, g++, correctness

[This snippet](http://ideone.com/icNly) (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232085/template-spaghetti)) compiles fine with g++ (as seen), so long the `template` before the return type is there. In contrast, VC10 does not compile that code with the following error:

> error C2244: 'A::getAttr' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

If I remove the `template`, VC10 is happy but g++ screams this error:

> error: non-template 'AttributeType' used as template
>   note: use 'A::template AttributeType' to indicate that it is a template

Is it again because of VC's broken two-phase look-up or what is the cause? Which compiler is right here? I suspect g++ to be correct, as I have a vague memory of `template` being needed here, like with the `rebind` template inside of allocators.

---

**Edit**: We have a winner: g++/GCC (surprise surprise...).

---

```
template <typename T, typename K>
class A {
public:
    T t;
    K k;

    template <int i, int unused = 0>
    struct AttributeType{
    };

    template <int i>
    AttributeType<i> getAttr();

};

template <typename T, typename K>
template <int i>
typename A<T, K>::template AttributeType<i> A<T, K>::getAttr() {
//                ^^^^^^^^ -- needed or not?
    return t;
}


int main(){
    A<int,int> a;
}
```

Comment: Post the code in the question.  Stack overflow supports and strongly encourages this.

Comment: In general the informal "reference compiler" for standard compliance is Comeau, you may try to submit your snippet [here](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) to view its verdict. - EDIT: tried now, the snippet compiles it fine as it is on Ideone.

Comment: @Merlyn: Wanted to keep this question short, done though.

Comment: clang++ 2.9 and Intel C/C++ 11.1 side with gcc too.

Comment: Occasionally I find myself needing `#ifdef` blocks for template code to compile happily in both VC2010 and GCC 4.6 this looks like one of those cases.

Comment: Wait, you are asking if MSVC or gcc gets it right with `template` and `typename` keywords?  MSVC 10?  Seriously?  MS's implementation of `template`s remains pretty horrid in the current one, let alone one that old.

Comment: @Yakk You _do_ realize that this question is over 3 years old?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GCC is right. `AttributeType` is a dependent template-name which is followed by angle bracket `<`, so the keyword `template` is required here to remove the ambiguity<sup>1</sup>, making it clear to the compiler that what is followed is a template-name. The rule is mentioned in §14.2/4:

> When the name of a member template
>   specialization appears after . or ->
>   in a postfix-expression, or after
>   nested-name-specifier in a
>   qualified-id, and the
>   postfix-expression or qualified-id
>   explicitly depends on a
>   template-parameter (14.6.2), the
>   member template name must be prefixed
>   by the keyword template. Otherwise the
>   name is assumed to name a
>   non-template.

<sup>1</sup> @Johannes has written a very good explanation here:

[Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names/613132#613132)

Comment: Thanks, that was the standard quote I was looking for.