# Nested templates workaround for MSVC2010?

Tags: c++, templates

I stumbled on the same problem of nested templates described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232294/which-compiler-is-right-template-before-templated-return-type-needed).

The following code :

```
# include <cstdlib>  // for std::size_t

template<std::size_t N>
class Outer
{
public :
  template<typename T>
  class Inner
  {
      public :
        inline Inner<T> & operator ++ (void) ;
        inline Inner<T>   operator ++ (int) ;
  } ;
} ;

template<std::size_t N>
template<typename T>
inline typename Outer<N>::template Inner<T> & Outer<N>::Inner<T>::operator ++ (void)
{   //                    ^^^^^^^^ Point Of Interest : MSVC is the only one who complains
    // preincrement
}

template<std::size_t N>
template<typename T>
inline typename Outer<N>::template Inner<T>   Outer<N>::Inner<T>::operator ++ (int)
{   //                    ^^^^^^^^ Point Of Interest
    // postincrement
}
```

compiles fine with MinGW 4.5 (i.e. gcc) as long as the `template` keyword is present in the return type, but this makes MSVC2010 complain about declaration/definition mismatch :

```
error C2244: 'Outer::Inner::operator ++' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
1>  definition
1>    'Outer::Inner &Outer::Inner::operator ++(void)'
1>  existing declarations
1>    'Outer::Inner Outer::Inner::operator ++(int)'
1>    'Outer::Inner &Outer::Inner::operator ++(void)' <- This is what it wants !
```

When removing the `template` keyword, MSVC compiles fine while gcc becomes angry :

```
error: non-template 'Inner' used as template
note: use 'Outer::template Inner' to indicate that it is a template
```

Accoding to the [post linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232294/which-compiler-is-right-template-before-templated-return-type-needed), MSVC seems to be the faulty. So my questions :

- How to adapt the above code in order to compile with both MSVC and GCC ?
  I really want to avoid this awful preprocessor hack :

  ```
  # ifdef MSVC
  # define nested_template 
  # else
  # define nested_template template
  # endif
  ```

And then use `nested_template` to please MSVC where it doesn't like `template`.

- If impossible, how to refactor/redesign the code to avoid the nested templates case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the define is the way to go for cross compiler support in so many places where you need the nested template. Boost does it too!

The alternative is to seperate all your nested templates in extra headers and have different include pathes in MSVC and GCC.

Comment: I didn't know that. In which boost library/libraries is it done ? I would like to see how the boost developers dealt with it.

Comment: @overcoder: IIRC it is used in the `boost::function` library for example. I think it was not directly for MSVC but other compilers got that problem too. Actually, the define should be in the config header of Boost (or somewhere around there).

Comment: Glad to hear your quick response ! I'll check that out.

Comment: @overcoder: Search for `BOOST_NESTED_TEMPLATE`, IIRC that was the name.

Comment: @overcode: Came across a similar macro today, one use is in `Boost.Range`, specifically `<boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp`. And it's called `BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME`.

Comment: Many thanks ! I checked the `boost` headers to find that `BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME` is heavily used to address a similar problem with the `typename` keyword. You deserve a full support badge !