# Inner class template keyword usage

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, gcc, cross-platform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which compiler is right? ‘template’ before templated return type needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232294/which-compiler-is-right-template-before-templated-return-type-needed)

If I have the following classes:

```
template <typename T1>
class OuterClass
{
    template <typename T2>
    class InnerClass
    {
    };
};
```

When I attempt to reference `OuterClass<int>::InnerClass<int>`, GCC complains that I need the `template` keyword to be used before `InnerClass`, but Visual Studio complains about the keyword. Obviously I can use a macro to get around the problem, but it feels a bit ugly. Who is right in this situation, and is there a better solution?

GCC:

```
OuterClass<int>::template InnerClass<int>
```

VS:

```
OuterClass<int>::InnerClass<int>
```

Solution:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#define INNER_TEMPLATE
#else
#define INNER_TEMPLATE template
#endif

OuterClass<int>:: INNER_TEMPLATE InnerClass<int>
```

Comment: i tried the code you posted and it says it misses a main function.

Comment: The question of how to best solve the dilemma has been discussed here (with no surprising results, though): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208203/nested-templates-workaround-for-msvc2010

Comment: I don't think it is a real duplicate, `OuterClass<int>` is different from the more generic `OuterClass<T>`.

Comment: I just compiled the `OuterClass<int>::InnerClass<int>` version with GCC without problems: which version do you have?

Comment: Post a real example please. I doubt that GCC really gave an error about `OuterClass<int>::InnerClass<int>`, which is correct code. It *would* give an error about use of a private member though.